# PHP loop only going around 9 times instead of ~45?

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($badLinkHolder); $i++)
    {
        if($badLinkHolder[$i][0] != "")
        {
            echo "<tr><td>{$i}</td><td>{$badLinkHolder[$i][0]}</td><td>{$badLinkHolder[$i][1]}</td></tr>";
        }
    }
```

Now, `$badLinkHolder` has around 45 entries which I can confirm by using `print_r()`. For some reason, this loop is only going around 9 times and I can't retrieve all of my data from the array.

Any help on this? I'm completely baffled.

Comment: how do you know that it's going 9 times?

Comment: Well, does $badLinkHolder have 45 filled [0] entries?

Comment: Could you post the contents of $badLinkHolder.

Comment: PErhaps you can provide a copy of your `print_r` of your data? There's nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Isn't it the case that for all the other 36 entries $badLinkHolder[$i][0] == "" ?

Comment: also, using count() function inside the loop isn't very good, since it will be called each time the loop "starts over".

Comment: @Yoda: count is not really expensive but `foreach` would be more elegant anyway, @Carlos: I think you are right must be the `if`

Comment: @RageZ, it could our could not, depends on the amount of code your dealing with (number of loops as well), and your need to have a fast system response. Anyway, I find good practice to use it outside the looping function.

Comment: @Yoda: yeah it's better anyway, you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, how did you know that it is going only 9 times? My guess is that you've seen only 9 rows in your table thus assuming that your loop only goes 9 times. You have a `if` statement that states that if `($badLinkHolder[$i][0] != "")`, only then you will print out the row.

On top of this, `foreach` would be better than `for` looping an array in PHP.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($badLinkHolder as $holder)
{
    if($holder[0] != "")
    {
        echo "<tr><td>{$i}</td><td>{$holder[0]}</td><td>{$holder[1]}</td></tr>";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop looks fine. However I'm not sure of the content of the array and I would suggest that you first try removing the if statement and replacing it with some dummy text. For example:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($badLinkHolder); $i++)
{
  echo "test $i";
}
```

That way, you can make sure that you are passing through the loop the correct number of times and it is not an error with the code inside the loop. Also, have you echoed the returned value of count($badLinkHolder)?

Answer (score 0):

Oh gawd, I'm an idiot. I was looking at the entries for $badLinkHolder before it went through a few functions that weren't working as normal and filled it with loads of null values.

Problem solved.

Comment: @Joshua: I thin a comment would have been better, anyway I think using `foreach` would be better